Line of charge next to infinitely long, grounded cylinder - valid solution?
There is a line of charge of density $\lambda$ at $r = a$ placed parallel next to an infinitely long, grounded, cylinder of radius $R$, centered at $r = 0$. What is the potential outside the cylinder?
Textbook answer is, that, the potential is the same as if there was an image charge (inside the cylinder) at $a^\prime = R^2 / a$ with charge density $\lambda^\prime = -\lambda$. While I understand the approach, I see a problem here: to me, "grounding" an object means to match its potential to the potential far away (infinity). As opposed to the cylinder, a grounded sphere has zero potential because, without adding any constants to the potential, only considering point charges, the potential will decay to 0 at infinity. We can add a constant $V_0$ to this potential and the sphere stays grounded, because the potential on the surface ($V_0$) matches the potential at infinity (also $V_0$).
Zangwill, Modern electrodynamics (p. 249) says about the grounded cylinder:

It is worth noticing that the choices in (8.39) do not give zero for
the constant value of the potential on the cylinder surface. To make
it zero, we must add a constant to the right side of (8.36). This
simple expedient is not possible for the sphere problem because the
charge and potential of a conducting sphere cannot be specified
independently. The difference arises because the point charge
potential (8.2) goes to zero at infinity while the line charge
potential (8.35) diverges at infinity

So Zangwill actually acknowledges that the potential at infinity diverges and seems to be not worried about it. Can we really talk about grounding, though? If "grounded" really means zero without any consideration for the value at infinity, then we can also put arbitrary image line of charge at $r = 0$ and shift the potential to zero by adding a constant: any of such configurations produces a zero (or constant) potential on the cylinder and diverging potential at infinity (except for one special value $\lambda^{\prime \prime} = +2 \lambda$, which results in a finite limit at infinity). WHich one is the right answer? To make it really simple to visualize, let's summarize, here $(a, b)$ is a pair (charge density, at what radius):

$(\lambda, a)$ - original line
$(\lambda, a) + (-\lambda, R^2 / a)$ - original line + image line, supposed answer, together produce constant potential on the cylinder, but diverging potential at infinity
$(\lambda, a) + (-\lambda, R^2 / a) + (\lambda^\prime, 0)$ - original line + image line + another image of arbitrary value at zero radius, together also produce constant potential on the cylinder, diverging potential at infinity
$(\lambda, a) + (-\lambda, R^2 / a) + (2 \lambda, 0)$ - original line + image line + another image with charge density equal to twice the original at zero radius, together produce constant potential on the cylinder, constant potential at infinity, but these two constants are not equal (and can't be made equal as there is no more freedom left in what lines can be placed in the system)

Last scenario is the closest we get to a "grounded cylinder", so why is it not "the" answer to this problem? And if a single image line is the accepted answer, because we don't care about the potential at infinity, why is any additional arbitrarily charged line at the center of the cylinder also not an equally valid answer?
This feels like this problem is badly defined, because the boundary condition is either way too arbitrary (can diverge at infinity), or impossible to satisfy.

It is indeed not quite well defined mathematically. However, physics is not maths, and we may arrange the orders of "infinity" to get a result that "looks real". We usually use this model where the length of the wire and cylinder is much longer than the distance between them. The grounded reference point is taken at a distance much further than the length of the wire, which has a well-defined potential.

Usually we just try to throw away the divergent parts of a model. For instance, a point charge or charged wire will have divergent potential on the charge or wire, and we will simply say that this problem is not going to be explained by this model.

@MaYe okay, so what is the actual answer? Which combination of image charge lines is the correct one and why?

The second one is good. In the scenario I proposed in an earlier comment, this will make the cylinder have the same potential as the reference point.

@MaYe "this will make the cylinder have the same potential as the reference point" - reference point where?

Yes, the problem is ill posed mathematically. You cannot ground the cylinder, i.e. set its voltage to the one at infinity. The best you can do is impose it to be an equipotential with a finite voltage difference with infinity, and it is the latter surrogate problem that is solved by the textbook answer. Quantitatively, set with no loss of generality $\lambda=2\pi$ and the radius of the original cylinder to $1$. With the charge at distance $a>1$, the textbook answer polar coordinates is (charge at $\phi=0$):
$$
V(r,\phi) = -\frac12\ln(a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\phi)+\frac12\ln(a^{-2}+r^2-2a^{-1}r\cos\phi) \\
V(r = 1) = -\ln a \neq V(r\to\infty) = 0
$$
The author's remark simply means that just assuming that the voltage between the cylinder and infinity is finite entirely determines the voltage (i.e. $V(r=1)-V(r\to\infty)=-\ln(a)$).
You can motivate the textbook solution by regularising your problem. Add another grounded  coaxial cylinder of radius $R>1$. Now place the charge between the two at distance $1<a<R$ from the axis. As you send $R\to\infty$, you should recover the "real" problem as you understood it originally. If the potential does converge, this would be your desired solution. You can solve for the potential in the region $1<r<R$ by the method of images or by multipole expansion:
$$
V^R(r,\phi) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty V_n^R(r)\cos(n\phi)
$$
You can check that as you send $R\to\infty$, you do recover:
$$
V^R(r,\phi) \to V(r,\phi) = -\frac12\ln(a^2+r^2-2ar\cos\phi)+\frac12\ln(a^{-2}+r^2-2a^{-1}r\cos\phi)+\ln a
$$
This is the textbook answer (original charge plus image charge) with an additive offset to satisfy $V(r=1)=0$.
By studying the convergence, you can now understand the discrepancy at infinity. The convergence as $R\to\infty$ is simple, not uniform in $r$. Physically, you have a separation of scale between the characteristic length for the potential to rise and one to fall back down to zero at infinity. Intuitively, you would expect the latter larger length scale to be $R$. Quantitatively, the only issue is with the monopole term $V_0^R$. You can compute it explicitly:
$$
V_0^R(r) = \begin{cases}
\left(1-\frac{\ln a}{\ln R}\right)\ln r & r\leq a\\
\ln a-\frac{\ln a}{\ln R}\ln r & r\geq a
\end{cases}
$$
It does satisfy the boundary conditions $V_0(1)=V_0^R(R)=0$, but as $R\to\infty$:
$$
V_0^R(r) \to V_0(r) =\begin{cases}
\ln r & r\leq a\\
\ln a & r\geq a
\end{cases}
$$
You get a second limiting potential by rescaling the distance $r = R\tilde r$ and the potential:
$$
V_0^R(\tilde r R)\ln R \xrightarrow{R\to\infty} \tilde V_0(\tilde r) = -\ln a\ln\tilde r
$$
which does vanish at $\tilde r = 1$. As a consistency check, you should match $V(x\to\infty)$ with $\tilde V(\tilde x\to0)$. Since you rescale the potential by $\ln R$, it consistent as $\tilde V(\tilde r\to 0)\to+\infty$. You can do better at large but finite $R$. The domain of validity of $\tilde V$ is for $\tilde r\gg 1/R$, and when $\tilde r= O(1/R)$, $\tilde V\sim \ln R\ln a$. This is consistent with the fact that $V(r\to\infty) = \ln a$.
The monopole term is the only one to be problematic, i.e. the higher multipole terms converge uniformly to zero. Therefore, you can apply the reasoning to the full potential:
$$
V^R(\tilde r R,\phi)\ln R \xrightarrow{R\to\infty} \tilde V(\tilde r,\phi) = -\ln a\ln\tilde r
$$
On a side note, you have a similar issue in 1D, which is easier to treat analytically. Take a uniformly charged plane placed next to a  grounded conducting plane. You can similarly regularise the problem by placing the charged plane between two conducting planes at the same potential. Quantitatively, in cartesian coordinates, say one conducting plane is at $x=0$, another at $x=D$ and the charged plane at $x=a$ with $0<a<D$. The potential is simply:
$$
V^D(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{D-a}Dx & x\leq a\\
\frac aD(D-x) & x \geq a
\end{cases}
$$
satisfying $V^D(0) = V^D(D)=0$. Sending $D\to\infty$ you have on the one hand:
$$
V^D(x) \to V(x) \begin{cases}
x & x\leq a\\
a & x \geq a
\end{cases}
$$
and on the other hand by rescaling $x=D\tilde x$:
$$
V^D(D\tilde x) \to \tilde V(\tilde x)=a(1-\tilde x)
$$
Similarly, you do have a simpler matching:
$$
V(x\to\infty)=\tilde V(\tilde x\to0) = a
$$

I now believe the textbook answer is the correct result through a more careful approach using renormalization boundary as you suggested. I found the expansion for $V^R (r, \phi)$ you mentioned and thus verified the results from your answer. I can see the monopole term charge density is proportional to $1/\log(R)$, and thus disappears as $R \to \infty$ and the leftover potential non-uniformly converges to a form that won't match the cylinder with $r \to \infty$, but given what the math tells us, it's the best we can do and the system really forms a dipole. Thank you for your detailed analysis.

I think this response expands on the one made by Ruffolo.  The equation for the electric potential arising from a static charge density is,
$$
\nabla^2 V = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
$$
This is a second order differential equation, requiring the value of V on two boundaries to determine it's value on the interior.  One boundary is surface of the cylinder, the other can be taken to be an enclosing cylindrical surface at a very large radius.  A grounded conducting cylinder would allow charge to flow in to create an equal potential surface.  As Ruffolo also stated, this makes the cylinder + line charge into a dipole.  The line charge at $a$ with an image of equal and opposite charge at $R^2/a$ would have a potential that goes like $\sim \frac{1}{r}$ at very large r, which is what you'd expect from a line charge and a parallel cylindrical conductor.  Hence, the line charge at $a$ and the image line charge at $R^2/a$ have the correct boundary conditions on the cylindrical surface at R and at infinity.  The other solutions you posed do not have the correct boundary conditions at infinity, they only match the boundary condition at $R$.

Grounding fixes the potential (usually to zero - but this is a matter of convention.) In this case ground is treated as an infinitely large object, whose potential and charge are not affected (to any reasonable degree of precision) by connecting something to it.
We also often assume the zero of potential to lie at infinity - this is true for a point charge, but this is not always the case - e.g., when dealing with an infinite linen of charge. (Note that when talking about an infinite line of charge infinity also becomes ambiguous term - depending whether one goes in radial direction or along the line of charge.)
So, although zero on the ground and zero in infinity are two common conventions, they are not necessarily the same, and should not necessarily be applied in the same problem. In other words, the infinity (in radial direction) and the infinitely large ground do not overlap.
It is also worth remembering that in any real setting these would be just approximations - the line of charge is not infinite, but we are at a very small distance from it (compared to its length.) Likewise, the ground is not infinite - as explained above. In other words, I would picture the cylinder as a small tube sticking out of a huger metallic sphere, with a needle suspended nearby, but not touching the sphere.
What grounding also means is that charge is free to flow into the grounded object, as to preserve its potential. This is the role of grounding in the problem discussed in Q.
